How to cancel popup notification of other apps
I know how to cancel notifications with the help of the NotificationListenerService
The code works well and the notifications are being canceled and not being displayed in the notification bar.
BUT...
On new devices with Android 14 (for example) I do see and hear the "popup notification"
Here is how to access them on an Android device:
open Settings - Notifications - App notifications - select application - Notification categories - tap on one of the categories - inspect the "Show as pop-up", now, you can disable or enable it
I am looking for a programmatic way to prevent from the popup notification to appear/make a sound, but haven't found any solution yet
I do have all the needed permissions in the manifest
This is how I cancel the notifications (it does work on all devices) but canceling notifications seems to have no affect on the popups) and as long as popup notifications are there, the fact that I cancelled the "notifications" doesn't really help me :|
public class MyNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

  public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
      String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
      if (isPkgBlocked(packageName)) {
          cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
      }
  }
.
.
.

Here is what I'm talking about in a picture:


What is a "popup notification"?

@CommonsWare you can see how it looks like here https://www.google.com/imgres?q=popup%20notification%20android&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs.cafebazaar.ir%2Fimages%2Fupload%2Fscreenshot%2Fcom.jamworks.disablenotificationpopups-41adc37b-6c2f-4dbb-83e6-9f797413604f.jpeg%3Fx-img%3Dv1%2Fresize%2Ch_600%2Clossless_false%2Foptimize&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcafebazaar.ir%2Fapp%2Fcom.jamworks.disablenotificationpopups%3Fl%3Den&docid=-kPsClkIIKJu4M&tbnid=ALxpSxDHMu1K3M&vet=12ahUKEwjj1aCow6SGAxUsRvEDHUPdAnUQM3oECEsQAA..i&w=1066&h=600&hcb=2&ved=2ahUKEwjj1aCow6SGAxUsRvEDHUPdAnUQM3oECEsQAA

and here https://www.gearrice.com/update/thats-right-disable-notification-popups/

Could you get permission for do not disturb mode management?

And on the other hand, is your service executed as foregroundService?

@ThattaSystems I have a foreground service in my app, in addition to the service that extends the NotificationListenerService

@ThattaSystems I will check about the do not disturb permission

@ThattaSystems getting  permission for do not disturb mode management didn't help

I imagine that apart from the permission you activated the no disturbance mode in your app

no, the purpose is to "silent" only notifications of specific apps

Some apps expose notification channels through their APIs. You might be able to query or modify these channels programmatically to potentially disable sounds or change the notification style (e.g., from popup to silent). However, this depends on the specific app's implementation and any code level implementation might not be universally applicable to all the apps or after the new update.

@BobSmith thanks, sounds interesting but not very stable

This is a very Samsung UI specific thing. I don't think it is possible to programatically manipulate it. What can be done, is maybe have a page, in your app that navigates to this setting, and educate the user what has to be done before navigating

@gtxtreme, thanks but it seems to be on other brands too, like Pixel (maybe more) while education users sometime can be done, in this case I prefer to find a way of doing it from the code. tx
